# Does String.matches(<pattern>) throw anything?

Tags: java, exception, patternsyntaxexception

I am using this method to determine whether the input string from a TextField in javafx has this pattern AB123CD with the pattern ("\D{2}\d{3}\D{2}")
I am using a try catch enclosure, which catches a (hand)thrown PatternSyntaxException.
I am asking this, because the PatternSyntaxException uses a String String Integer constructor, showing the exception like:
 error at index **int**

   ^
or something like that
My problem is that I can't figure out how to get the right index to put in the constructor, or whether I can use any other Exception in replacement

This is the part of the code:

```
try {
        if(!tfTarga.getText().matches("\\D{2}\\d{3}\\D{2}"))
            throw new PatternSyntaxException(tfTarga.getText(), tfTarga.getText(), 0);
        else {
            this.olCCar.add(new CCar(new ContractCars(new Contract(this.comboCont.getValue()), this.tfTarga.getText(), LocalDate.now(), Integer.parseInt(this.tfPrezzo.getText()))));
            this.tfTarga.setText("");
            this.tfPrezzo.setText("");
        }
    } catch (PatternSyntaxException e) {
        alert("Error", "Format Error", e.getLocalizedMessage());
    }
```

Comment: Please show us the entire relevant code, or at least enough of it to get your point across.  Your regex looks fine, but that doesn't mean your code is OK.

Comment: PatternSyntaxException is supposed to signal an error in the syntax of a pattern (as its name implies). I(s not supposed to signal that a string doesn't match a regexp. Just show your alert inside the if block. No need for an exception.

Answer (score 0):

[PatternSyntaxException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/PatternSyntaxException.html) is a `RuntimeException` which is thrown when there's any syntax error in regex. There's no compile time exception thrown by  `String::matches` method as it internally calls `Pattern` class's static method `matches`. Here's the source code:

```
public static boolean matches(String regex, CharSequence input) {
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);
        Matcher m = p.matcher(input);
        return m.matches();
    }
```

Thus here you are catching `PatternSyntaxException` because you are explicitly throwing `PatternSyntaxException` here:

```
if(!tfTarga.getText().matches("\\D{2}\\d{3}\\D{2}"))
            throw new PatternSyntaxException(tfTarga.getText(), tfTarga.getText(), 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

`String.matches` throws `PatternSyntaxException` when the **regular expression's syntax is invalid**. It's not used to tell whether the input matches the regex pattern.

Since `\\D{2}\\d{3}\\D{2}` is a valid regex, this `catch (PatternSyntaxException e)` will never be executed.